# Collasping bootstrap div goes under the bottom div

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap collapse class in a list of divisions.
but collapsing division goes under the bottom item.
It needs to resize browser after collapse to work well.

```
 <div>
 <div class="footer-co-src row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 details-fly">
            <a  class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"  aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseDetails-1" data-target="#collapseDetails-1">Button</a>
    </div>
  </div>

        <div class="collapse row" id="collapseDetails-1">
          <div class="card card-body"> sth to show 
          </div>
        </div>
 <div>
```

I have multiple of these divs, but showing div will be under the next item.

Comment: kindly include a minimal working example which can recreate this issue and you'll get help from the community much more faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no bug in this piece of code. You are probably using some JS library that changes position type to `position:absolute` or `position:fix`.

Check any list managing JS/Jquery source on your whole page.

Answer (score 0):

Check the css position:fixed is coming from which library. You can check in inspect elements. And then use this stylesheet library before the bootstrap library in html.